# How to check for version of app and request users to update?

Tags: objective-c, ios, version, uialertview

How can I check if the user has the current version of my app and also pop up a message to request them to update their app version?

Something like what you would see below.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to have a WebService on your server (or something similar) that your app requests at startup, to know which is the latest version available. (If you don't have a WS yet and really don't want to implement one for that, you may also simply use an XML or text file that contains the version too)

Then compare this version retrieved from your server with the current version of the application, using `[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]`.

If they are different, you can display the alertview and redirect to `itms-apps://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftwareUpdate?id=[APPID]&mt=8` (replacing `APPID` with your *iTunes Connect App ID*), which is the link that will make your iPhone open the AppStore application directly on your application's update page

Comment: An improvement to this would be to send a request for a user notification to your server.  This request would include device type, application version, iOS version, and various other diagnostic information.  Then your server could decide, based on that information, which message to send to the application.  For example, if you found a major bug that only affected certain devices, you could let the affected users know that you've submitted a bug fix to Apple.

Comment: Note that since this answer, Apple did release the [iTunes Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html), so you can call `http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=<your-app-id-here>`  to get a JSON containing some metadata about your app, including its version on the store. You can compare it with the version in your Info.plist (`CFBundleVersion`) and trigger an alert when they are different. You can even use `SKStoreProductViewController` to present the page of your app in the AppStore directly integrated into your app.

Answer (score 12):

To check to see if you have the latest version just query iTunes for app data using the following query (note: change the id to match your app's id from iTunesConnect):

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=520604518

This returns a JSON dictionary which is very easy to convert to an NSDictionary to use directly within your code, then all you need to do is pull out the value for the "version" key and compare it against your apps version number (see version key/value bolded below):

```
{
    "resultCount": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "kind": "software",
            "features": [],
            "supportedDevices": [
                "all"
            ],
            "isGameCenterEnabled": false,
            "artistViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/d-m-holdings/id388608883?uo=4",
            "artworkUrl60": "http://a899.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/086/Purple/v4/6d/b3/05/6db305aa-c685-558b-8c8e-8b7245375ce1/IconAudio.png",
            "screenshotUrls": [
                "http://a86.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/078/Purple/v4/8f/ff/47/8fff4783-f2e4-fe3f-ef92-96d67d66c12b/mzl.dwbdvxny.png",
                "http://a731.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/097/Purple/v4/cb/65/f6/cb65f613-408a-dffe-fb36-165db0c1a360/mzl.jexyhdnq.png",
                "http://a940.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/097/Purple/v4/f6/26/a1/f626a18c-691f-7345-8d3d-f19713144818/mzl.llsgsagl.png",
                "http://a185.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/071/Purple/v4/7d/5e/bc/7d5ebcad-7755-e772-727c-65de99effd60/mzl.zuyvhebk.png",
                "http://a48.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/096/Purple/v4/d6/f5/f1/d6f5f108-10ab-3738-26cf-5ce82c6bb690/mzl.ijtyynie.png"
            ],
            "ipadScreenshotUrls": [],
            "artworkUrl512": "http://a672.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/100/Purple/v4/e3/cb/5d/e3cb5d2d-f1a8-8b80-3a91-58be8f654710/mzm.uogqezwx.png",
            "artistId": 388608883,
            "artistName": "D&M Holdings",
            "price": 0,
            **"version": "1.0.5",**
            "description": "Designed to enhance the listening experience with Denon’s new line of Music Maniac™ headphones, the Denon Audio app is designed for the on-the-go audiophile. The Denon Audio app features a premium audio player that lets you experience the best possible sound quality from your iPod music library and favorite Internet radio stations. Create & save custom EQ curves, create & save instant playlists, enjoy internet radio stations via the built-in TuneIn service, and more. The Denon Audio app will quickly replace all of your other music apps.\n \nThe Denon Audio app features a customizable graphical equalizer that lets you contour your own sound by directly manipulating more than 1000 discrete bands of equalization without adding spatial distortion or decreasing sound quality. Pump up the bass, restore those highs, and start jammin’! \n \nEQ FEATURES:\n \n• Graphical equalizer for your iPod music library and streaming Internet Radio\n• 1000 possible discrete bands\n• 10 built in EQ Presets\n• Create and save your own EQ Presets\n• Bypass mode to quickly compare the original and equalized audio\n• Real-time spectrum analyzer\n• Linear phase design\n• No spatial distortion\n\nIPOD MUSIC LIBRARY FEATURES:\n\n• Enhances your listening experience with Denon Music Maniac Headphones or other audio playback devices such as docking stations, a/v receivers, car stereos via USB, Bluetooth, or Airplay.\n• Powerful queue based playback system lets you build and order your own playlist on the fly.\n• Save the playback queue as a new playlist\n• A single song, all songs on an album, all songs by an artist, and all songs in a genre can easily be added to the now playing queue.\n• Supports both portrait and landscape modes for browsing, playing, and equalizing\n• Shuffle and repeat playback modes\n• iPod library browsing by Playlist, Artist, Album, Song, Genre, Composer, Compilation, and Podcast (no importing needed)\n\nINTERNET RADIO FEATURES:\n\n• The TuneIn service provides global access to Internet radio – covering over 70,000 radio stations and 2 million on-demand programs including sports, news, talk, music and comedy. \n• Browse Internet radio stations by location, genre, language or Podcast (on-demand programs).\n• Powerful search feature for your iPod music library and Internet Radio \n• Save your favorite Internet Radio stations or programs as convenient presets and share them with  other TuneIn compatible devices\n• Ability to choose high or low quality streams offered by broadcasters\n \nADDITIONAL FEATURES:\n\n• Streams music over AirPlay to any Denon AirPlay compatible receiver or HiFi product\n• Share what you’re listening to via Facebook, Twitter, Email, or Text Message (iMessage)\n\nNOTICES:\n \n• The Denon Audio app requires iOS 5 or later and works with the iPhone 3GS or newer, the iTouch 3rd generation or newer, and all iPads (in 2x mode). \n• DRM protected iTunes music is NOT supported by the Denon Audio app (or any 3rd party music app)\n• iTunes Match will be supported in a future update \n• WiFi or data connection required to stream Internet radio",
            "currency": "USD",
            "genres": [
                "Music",
                "Lifestyle"
            ],
            "genreIds": [
                "6011",
                "6012"
            ],
            "releaseDate": "2012-05-29T07:00:00Z",
            "sellerName": "D&M Holdings Inc.",
            "bundleId": "com.dm-holdings.denon-audio",
            "trackId": 520604518,
            "trackName": "Denon Audio",
            "primaryGenreName": "Music",
            "primaryGenreId": 6011,
            "releaseNotes": "• Added 4\" display support for the iPhone 5 and 5th generation iPod Touch\n\n• Added an audio limiter function to protect against possible distortion introduced from pushing the EQ too high\n\n• Displays the Shuffle, Repeat, AirPlay, and Share icons as well as the scan/scrub controls on the \"Now Playing\" screen by default (so everyone knows they are included in the app). Tap the cover art to hide/show these controls",
            "formattedPrice": "Free",
            "wrapperType": "software",
            "trackCensoredName": "Denon Audio",
            "trackViewUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/denon-audio/id520604518?mt=8&uo=4",
            "contentAdvisoryRating": "4+",
            "artworkUrl100": "http://a672.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/100/Purple/v4/e3/cb/5d/e3cb5d2d-f1a8-8b80-3a91-58be8f654710/mzm.uogqezwx.png",
            "languageCodesISO2A": [
                "ZH",
                "DE",
                "EN",
                "ES",
                "FR",
                "JA",
                "NL"
            ],
            "fileSizeBytes": "9060882",
            "sellerUrl": "http://www.usa.denon.com/headphones",
            "averageUserRatingForCurrentVersion": 4.5,
            "userRatingCountForCurrentVersion": 329,
            "trackContentRating": "4+",
            "averageUserRating": 4.5,
            "userRatingCount": 471
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is some code to accomplish this task. -rrh

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=%@",APPSTORE_ID]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if (!error) {
                               NSError* parseError;
                               NSDictionary *appMetadataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&parseError];
                               NSArray *resultsArray = (appMetadataDictionary)?[appMetadataDictionary objectForKey:@"results"]:nil;
                               NSDictionary *resultsDic = [resultsArray firstObject];
                               if (resultsDic) {
                                   // compare version with your apps local version
                                   NSString *iTunesVersion = [resultsDic objectForKey:@"version"];

                                   NSString *appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
                                   if (iTunesVersion && [appVersion compare:iTunesVersion] != NSOrderedSame) { // new version exists
                                       // inform user new version exists, give option that links to the app store to update your app - see AliSoftware's answer for the app update link
                                       UIAlertView *alert = [UIAlertView bk_showAlertViewWithTitle:APP_NAME message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"New version %@ available. Update required.",iTunesVersion] cancelButtonTitle:@"update" otherButtonTitles:nil handler:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {


                                        NSString *iTunesLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id%@?mt=8",APPSTORE_ID];
                                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
                                       }];
                                       [alert show];
                                   }
                               }
                           } else {
                               // error occurred with http(s) request
                               NSLog(@"error occurred communicating with iTunes");
                           }
                       }];
```

Comment: But According to app-store review guidelines "Apps that scrape any information from Apple sites (for example from apple.com, iTunes Store, App Store, iTunes Connect, Apple Developer Programs, etc.) or create rankings using content from Apple sites and services will be rejected"

Comment: Using the iTMS Web Service is not what I'd call "scrapping" (which generally mean "extract data from a content not designed for parsing" like extracting info from a Web page in HTML). This is a Web Service and by definition has been created in order to let developers get and parse that information (and it's documented and all), as long as you don't abuse it. If you even only use it to query info about your own application and not others, it seems hard to qualify it as overuse of the service.

Comment: The above code is almost working as of today. I had to modify appMetadataDictionary as it is not the direct result from apple. The result is a dictionary with an array having all keys in the first position.

Comment: can you provide the link where Apple's guidelines regarding this or any apple document?